# static content deploy deletes magento

Tags: magento2

I run

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

and it deletes my magento install!!

it deletes

```
index.php
app/
lib/
js/
dev/
feeds/
skin/
```

What the hell is wrong with it?

Comment: It something wrong with else mistak, above command can't delete list of files and folder.

Comment: and yet it did, it happened several times. Obviously this is not normal behaviour, but what could possibly corrupt that command in that way?